# How to relate key words of a sentence to questions?

Tags: nltk, stanford-nlp

I am trying to build a question answering system. I am trying to analyse text being used. I could get named entities from data(used NLTK, python). And also on query side, I could find named entities and get the question focus. Now I want to relate the key words in a sentence to questions like what, how, when etc. I mean, I want to find out what kind of answers can be found from a sentence.

For example, if a sentence is:
Russia is the largest country in Asia.

I should be able to get
Russia - What, which
in Asia - where

How can I get this relation ?

Comment: Try looking for `Entity-linking` and `Slot-filling` from the `Knowledge Base Population` researches. http://www.nist.gov/tac/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a mapping from WH words to named entity tags? If so, my recommendation is to just hard-code the mapping -- there aren't that many named entity tag / WH word pairs.

Another approach you could try is matching dependency trees. For example, the edge from *country* to *Russia* (nsubj) in "*Russia is the largest country in Asia*" is the same edge as that between *what* and *Russia* in "*What is the largest country in Asia?*"